# React: Uncaught TypeError: Illegal constructor at ReactCompositeComponent.js

Tags: reactjs, react-router

I have three React modules: Customers, Products, Locations. All of them are structured the same way. (I got Customers working, then copied it changing names where needed.) Customers and Products work as expected.

Problem with Locations:

When the users clicks on an item in a list, instead of rendering the Location component, I get this error:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Illegal constructor
at ReactCompositeComponent.js:303
at measureLifeCyclePerf (ReactCompositeComponent.js:73)
at ReactCompositeComponentWrapper._constructComponentWithoutOwner (ReactCompositeComponent.js:302)
at ReactCompositeComponentWrapper._constructComponent (ReactCompositeComponent.js:277)
at ReactCompositeComponentWrapper.mountComponent (ReactCompositeComponent.js:185)
at Object.mountComponent (ReactReconciler.js:43)
at ReactCompositeComponentWrapper._updateRenderedComponent (ReactCompositeComponent.js:762)
at ReactCompositeComponentWrapper._performComponentUpdate (ReactCompositeComponent.js:721)
at ReactCompositeComponentWrapper.updateComponent (ReactCompositeComponent.js:642)
at ReactCompositeComponentWrapper.receiveComponent (ReactCompositeComponent.js:544)
```

The list is generated by LocationList.jsx:

```
import React from "react";
import { Link } from "react-router-dom";
import PropTypes from "prop-types";
import { v4 } from "uuid";

function LocationList({locations, onDeletingLocation}) {

function deleteLocation(locationId) {
 event.preventDefault();

 onDeletingLocation(locationId);
}

return (
 <div className="container">
  {Object.keys(locations).map((locationId) => {
    let location = locations[locationId];
    return <div key={v4()}>
      <Link
        to={`/admin/locations/${location.id}`}
      >
        <p>{location.locationName}</p>
      </Link>
      <button onClick={() => {deleteLocation(location.id);}}>Delete</button>
    </div>;
  }
  )}
  </div>
 );
}

LocationList.propTypes = {
  locations: PropTypes.object,
  onDeletingLocation: PropTypes.func
};

export default LocationList;
```

This is the Location.jsx that should be rendered:

```
import React from "react";
import PropTypes from "prop-types";
import EditLocationForm from "./../Locations/EditLocationForm";

class Location extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
  super(props);
  const location = props.locations[props.match.params.locationId];

this.state = {
  locationName: location.locationName,
  locationAddress: location.locationAddress,
  locationPostalCode: location.locationPostalCode,
  locationDescription: location.locationDescription,
  id: location.id
};

  this.handleChange = this.handleChange.bind(this);
  this.handleEditFormSubmission = 
  this.handleEditFormSubmission.bind(this);
 }

handleChange(event) {
  const target = event.target;
  const value = target.value;
  const name = target.name;

  this.setState({
    [name]: value
   });
  }

handleEditFormSubmission(event) {
event.preventDefault();

this.props.onEditLocation(
  {
    locationName: this.state.locationName,
    locationAddress: this.state.locationAddress,
    locationPostalCode: this.state.locationPostalCode,
    locationDescription: this.state.locationDescription,
    id: this.state.id
  });
}

  render() {
   const location = this.state;
    return (
    <div>
     <div className="container">
      <h3>{this.state.locationName}</h3>
      <p>{this.state.locationAddress}</p>
      <p>{this.state.locationPostalCode}</p>
      <p>{this.state.locationDescription}</p>
      <p>{this.state.id}</p>
    </div>

    <EditLocationForm
      location={location}
      onEditLocation={this.props.onEditLocation}
      onChange={this.handleChange}
      onEditFormSubmission={this.handleEditFormSubmission}/>
   </div>
   );
  }
}

Location.propTypes = {
 match: PropTypes.object,
 locations: PropTypes.object,
 locationName: PropTypes.string,
 onEditLocation: PropTypes.func
 };

export default Location;
```

What would cause this error? Does anyone have any fixes? I can't find any differences between these two files and their Customer and Product counter parts.

Answer (score 2):

I found it. Apparently "Location" is a reserved word. I changed it to "Locution" and the bug is fixed.

Comment: In my case, a component was also imported using a keyword but no relevant import provided to specify I meant that particular component and not the keyword.

Answer (score 0):

On the constructor you should put a constant as you did on `const location = props.locations[props.match.params.locationId];` on the `Location.jsx` file.

If you want to set the "location" on the constructor, it should go as `this.location =....`